# How to visually display dependencies of a package?

Tags: software-recommendation, package-management, dependencies

This is just for fun and curiosity: is there a tool using which I can **visually** see the **dependencies** of a **package** as a graph?

That is, the packages that a given package depends on. This can be a command-line tool that displays using ASCII graphics (like tree or Mercurial's graphlog) or a GUI tool that shows the dependency graph visually. Any other combination of tools that can show the dependencies visually works too.

Comment: And what would the axes of the graph be?

Comment: @vasa1: Vertices would be packages and edges are the dependencies.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

#### debtree

According to [the application's website](https://web.archive.org/web/20180516123936/http://collab-maint.alioth.debian.org/debtree/), the `debtree` package provides *"package dependency graphs on steroids"*.

**Note: This is also very useful when planning software upgrades. This application is able to graph dependencies against packages which have not yet been installed on your system.** This will read from the `sources.list` file (usually located at `/etc/apt/sources.list`) and it will perform a live query using that list.

The following diagram is an example of running `debtree` against the package `dpkg`. Here is a map of its dependencies:

[image]

To install `debtree` from the command line(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) enter the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install debtree
```

#### Usage

- Create a .dot file (a directed graph drawing - see the `man dot` manpage):

  ```
    debtree --with-suggests <package> >out.dot
  ```
- Create a graph (PNG) from a .dot file:

  ```
    dot -T png -o out.png out.dot
  ```
- Create a graph (Postscript) and view it using Okular:

  ```
    debtree <package> | dot -Tps | okular - &
  ```

Be aware that when running this application against larger packages (e.g. gedit), the images can quickly become unwieldy and illegible.

Note that [`apt-rdepends`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/apt-rdepends.1.html) can also be used in a similar manner, but piping output into a graphic is a bit more convoluted, in my opinion.

See also:
[Ubuntu debtree man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/debtree.1.html)

Comment: `--no-skip` or even `--show-all` are very useful options to include more packages like `libc6`.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe not so "graphical" but if you prefer not installing any extra packages you can run

```
apt-cache rdepends <package>
```

Take a look also to `depends` option.

You also have:

- `apt rdepends <package>`
- Use [this script](https://gist.github.com/damphat/6214499), `apt-rdepends-tree <package>`
- `apt-rdepends <package>` or as [debtree](https://askubuntu.com/a/261808/349837) `apt-rdepends --dotty package | springgraph > dependencies.png`

Answer (score 1):

The command-line tool Apitude is a great tool for looking at dependencies. no fancy graphs, but it does give you a nice hierarchic representation of dependencies for a specific package.

Comment: Nathan Cazell: Could you elaborate how I can view this hierarchical graph for a given package?

Comment: when you open Aptitude just search for a package using / then hit enter for the package you want and it will show all the information about the package including a dependency tree with unmet dependencies and also conflicting packages.

Comment: Nathan Cazell: Are you referring to the command-line aptitude tool?

Comment: Edited. Sorry for not clarifying earlier