# Looking for unused debs in my Ubuntu

Tags: package-management

For example, I can extract information about every files of installed packages. Thereafter, I can do `find -ls` with `-mmin` & `-mtime` somehow, I can draw a graph of absolutelly unused packages.

Is there ready solution?

Edit: I found `popularity-contest`
Here: [Is there a usage count for packages or programs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118886/is-there-a-usage-count-for-packages-or-programs)

I'm interesting in graphic interpretation, something like Gnome's [Baobab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Baobab) or KDE's [FileLight](http://utils.kde.org/projects/filelight).

Comment: See [Generating list of manually installed packages and querying individual packages](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2389/generating-list-of-manually-installed-packages-and-querying-individual-packages) and [How to visually display dependencies of a package?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/261772/how-to-visually-display-dependencies-of-a-package).

Answer (score 0):

mtime is for modified time. Maybe you want atime,  but for performance reasons it is disabled by default.